# iOS Swift numberOfSectionsInTableView VS numberOfRowsInSection

Tags: ios, uitableview

Can somebody please explain the difference between `numberOfSectionsInTableView` VS `numberOfRowsInSection`?

What does Section imply here? I understand that we've a table with rows. I just can't get to understand Section.

Comment: check out this link....https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewStyles/TableViewCharacteristics.html

Answer (score 3):

Rows in tables can be grouped into sections: [image: Screenshot]

`numberOfSections` gives you the number of sections (duh).
`numberOfRowsInSection` then gives you the number of rows per section. Sections are optional, it is possible to simply use a single section.

Answer (score 1):

numberOfSectionsInTableView should be default 1 if you just want to have a table with any number of rows.

numberOfRowsInSection is the number of rows you can use in each of your selected sections. (usually you have a data collection and make it the length of this collection)

A section is basically a logic subsection of your table and can have different headers and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can have two types of UITableViews, Plain or Grouped, and you can change that in eg. the tableviews properties in the storyboard. Number of sections refers to the number of sections that the tableview is going to have. A section is a group of Rows, sometimes with a header. Numbers of rows in section refers to the actual number of rows that a section has. So if you have 3 sections, you can define how many rows each section should have.

Answer (score 0):

Section is some kind of groupation, each section has own number of cells.

To have better understanding take a look at phonebook.

Each letter is section, and each section has contacts under that letter.

You can use section to jump to some part of table or to have grouped informations etc.

Another example would be Settings. You have general, security etc.

Answer (score 0):

Sections are subdivisions that are filled with rows.

For example, in the Contacts app, each letter is a section that is filled with rows.

A UITableView can be simple with just one section or complex with multiple sections that each have a custom number of rows, header and footer

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation**

1. `numberOfSectionsInTableView` means `UITableview` can have multiple
   section.You can give title in Section.
2. `numberOfRowsInSection` means each Sections at least should has one
   row.

   **Example:**

   ```
      Fruits
         Apple
         Orange
         PineApple
         Guva
         Bannana

      Vegetable
         Onion
         Potato
   ```

`Fruits`,`Vegetable` is a Section.

And each section has `NumberOfRow`

So `numberOfSectionsInTableView` return 2 as there are 2 section(Fruits,Vegetable).
And `numberOfRowsInSection` return 5 for fruits Section and 2 for vegetable section respectively

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain you with example,

If you would like to display category (Section/Group In short) in your application called, Mobile Devices & Tablets.

In Mobile section you will display list of mobiles where in case of Tablets section you will display list of tablets.

So in above case there is 2 sections & n (n will be number of devices) number of devices/tablets in each section.

Hope it clear your doubt.